# Grunt.js manipulate parent directory

Tags: wordpress, drupal, gruntjs, structure

I'm trying to make a build structure where files aren't just "floating about".

The reason for this is that I'm using Drupal and don't want to have the gruntfile, package.json and "node_modules"-folder placed loosely in the "themes"-folder.

My desired file structure:

```
- sites
    - all
        - themes
            - grunt_environment
                - Gruntfile.coffee
                - node_modules
                - src
                - package.json
            - theme_name
                - theme_name.info
```

I'm using `grunt-contrib-clean` and want to clean up my "theme_name"-folder each time I re-build my project. Unfortunately I get the following message:

`Warning: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory. Use --force to continue.`

So I guess my options are:
1 - Live with the fact that files are "floating about" in the themes folder.
2 - Find another way of structuring my files
3 - Clean the folder manually

or (what I hope for):

4 - Set an option to allow certain folders to be deleted by the `grunt-contrib-clean` module.

So - I'd really like to go with the 4th option, but the 2nd could do if anyone has a clever way of structuring my files.

Anyone who's experienced and overcome a similar structuring problem when working with Drupal (or Wordpress for that matter?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `force` option of `grunt-contrib-clean` to `true` to delete files outside of your current working directory. It avoids deleting outside the `cwd` to avoid accidentally deleting your entire system.

```
clean:
  options: force: true
```

A better option, IMO, is to put the `Gruntfile.coffee`, `node_modules`, and `package.json` at the base of your project.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the advice in terms of structuring as well.